# Objective C - Categories and Inheritance - Add method to base and add override to derived class

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, categories

I know that categories should not be used to override a method in the class they are extending. However, what about the following scenario.

Consider the classes:

**Base.h**

```
#import <Foundation/NSObject.h>

@interface Base: NSObject { NSNumber *n; }
@end
```

**Derived.h**

```
#import "Base.h"

@interface Derived: Base { NSString *s; }
@end
```

With categories:

**Base+Serialize.h**

```
#import "Base.h"

@interface Base (Serialize)
- (NSString*)serialize;
@end
```

**Base+Serialize.m**

```
#import "Base+Serialize.h"

@implementation Base (Serialize)
- (NSString*)serialize
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", n];
}

@end
```

**Derived+Serialize.h**

```
#import "Derived.h"

#import "Base+Serialize.h"

@interface Derived (Serialize)
- (NSString*)serialize;
@end
```

**Derived+Serialize.m**

```
#import "Derived+Serialize.h"

@implementation Derived (Serialize)
- (NSString*)serialize
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", s, [super serialize]];
}

@end
```

Obviously, this is a contrived/simplified example. But it works well to demonstrate what I would like to do. Essentially, I want to provide additional functionality to multiple classes in an inheritance hierarchy.

Is this a safe/valid use of categories? Any gotchas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an acceptable way to use categories. Categories do actually add the message to the class, so the message will work just like any other message. This includes inheritance.

Perhaps one thing to watch out for is that you can run into name collisions. I don't know how the runtime handles them, but if two categories supply the same message you may have unexpected behavior since the message you expect is not being called. That being said, you may just want a name which is a little more distinctive than `serialize`, unless of course, you need that name (e.g. you have an informal protocol).

Comment: Thank you for confirming that there aren't any hidden issues with this approach. That is reassuring. Your comment about the name is valid, I will take it into consideration. If no objections show up anytime soon, I will accept your answer.

Comment: So would the example in the question be a name collision then? With two categories implementing a serialize method. Can we be certain the correct one will be called?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem like a very good object model. Base.h and Derived.h seem fine. What about making a Protocol to define the serialize: method, rather than a category? That would be a little cleaner. Base.h would indicate that it would implement the protocol and Derived could override the method as needed.

Comment: Yes, for the provided example, that would certainly be a possibility. However, categories have their advantages. For one, they provide another way of structuring your code, allowing you to keep optional functionality out of the original class. Or, let's say that Base and Derived are provided by another library and I do not want to modify the source.

Comment: This other library is in c++? In objective-c, all methods can be overridden in the derived class, despite it's previous implementation. However, if the lib is in c++, it makes sense to objective-c++ syntax to override previous virtual methods.

Comment: @RaphaelAyres: If I understand correctly, you are suggesting to provide the additional methods in subclasses of the library classes. However, this would not be feasible in the case of an existing inheritance hierarchy. As far as I know, there is no way to create `MyBase` and `MyDerived` and inject them into the hierarchy so that `MyDerived < Derived < MyBase < Base`.

Comment: But, if the library provide you a virtual interface to implement, then you could create your own classes based on the same interface, and inject then back into the library once they have the same signature as the other classes. Of course, if you want to add functionality, it will not work for the library, but if you just want to give personal implementation, virtual interfaces is the way to go. Just remember this works if your library is in C++, if it's in Objective-c, work with protocols the same way, as pointed by the answer...