# UITextView category inheritance fails to work as expected on iOS7 device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, objective-c-category

I've had working code for categories of UITextField and UITextField similar to the following on iOS5 and iOS6 devices. However, the UITextView category method does not appear to be called on an iOS7 device (an iPhone5S). The code is:

```
@interface UIView (CustomCategory)
-(void) someCategoryMethod;
@end

@implementation UIView (CustomCategory)
-(void) someCategoryMethod {
    NSLog(@"UIView category methods appear to work.");
}
@end

@interface UITextField (CustomCategory)
-(void) someCategoryMethod;
@end

@implementation UITextField (CustomCategory)
-(void) someCategoryMethod {
    [super someCategoryMethod];
    NSLog(@"UITextField category methods appear to work.");
}
@end

@interface UITextView (CustomCategory)
-(void) someCategoryMethod;
@end

@implementation UITextView (CustomCategory)
-(void) someCategoryMethod {
    [super someCategoryMethod];
    NSLog(@"UITextView category methods appear to work.");
}
@end

void testFunction() {
    UITextView* textView = [[[UITextView alloc] init] autorelease];
    [textView someCategoryMethod];

    UITextField* textField = [[[UITextField alloc] init] autorelease];
    [textField someCategoryMethod];
}
```

On an iOS5 device, this (testFunction) prints:

```
UIView category methods appear to work.
UITextView category methods appear to work.
UIView category methods appear to work.
UITextField category methods appear to work.
```

However, on an iOS7 device this prints:

```
UIView category methods appear to work.
UIView category methods appear to work.
UITextField category methods appear to work.
```

So the UIView category method is actually being called in preference to the UITextView category method, which appears to contradict [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9419666).

Could anyone clarify whether the above code should work as expected (i.e. as on iOS5 and iOS6)?

Comment: Your sample code does not reproduce the output you list in your question under iOS7. It outputs with inheritance as expected.

Comment: @FruityGeek: The code *definitely* produces the stated output on the iPhone5S I'm using (I therefore assumed it applied to iOS7, since I don't have any other iOS7 devices to test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Avoid Category Method Name Clashes**
>
> Because the methods declared in a category are added to an existing
>   class, you need to be very careful about method names.
>
> If the name of a method declared in a category is the same as a method
>   in the original class, **or a method in another category on the same
>   class (or even a superclass)**, the behavior is **undefined** as to
>   which method implementation is used at runtime.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html